# mistake in mysql root plugin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 16.04. I've installed LAMP server and wanted to change root plugin from `authsocket` to `mysql_native_password`, but I made a mistake and wrote `mysqlnative_password` and now when I try to run

> mysql -uroot

I get an error

> ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysqlnative_password' is not loaded

How can I fix it?

Comment: Edit your configuration? You changed it once, change it back.

Comment: @tadman unfortunatelly, I can't edit it back because I need to run mysql but it actually is my problem - i cant run mysql. Maybe there is another way to change this setting?